# Identifying an object on a page with changing title

Tags: automated-tests, qtp

There is a webelement on my page containing a text I need to parse. The problem is that when I add this object to the repository, it belongs under the page I am on and thus will not work with other pages (accessing like Page("..).WebElement..)which is just the same one just a with different title. I know I should use descriptive programming to identify the object but could not find the way it works.
Also I would need to identify the element on the page and get its properties. Some articles say it can be based on the name but there is no name when I objectSpy the object.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the `Page` objects don't contain their `title` as part of their description therefore the same `WebElement` should work under different pages.
You should first check that your `Page`'s description doesn't include any unneeded properties.

It's more likely that the `WebElement`'s description matches the element on the first page but not that on the second page. 
When QTP fails to identify the object it specifies which object it can't find, check whether it's complaining about the `WebElement` or the `Page`.